# FFMPEG attach thumbnail to first frame of the video

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to attach/append an image (something like youtube) to first frame of the video, i tried this command :

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:0 attached_pic out.mp4
```

But it doesnt working, the first frame is not my custom image

my ffmpeg version:

> ffmpeg version n4.4-80-gbf87bdd3f6-20210830 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: Copy and paste *all* text from `ffmpeg -i video.mp4`. It is needed for you to get an answer.

Comment: @llogan thats all of it, i did these: 1. having video.mp4 2. having image.png in same directory, then i open cmd and paste the command, the out.mp4 created but it doesnt have any thumbnail, this is the result https://pastebin.com/TTSLrDgu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to concatenate a frame to the beginning.

1. Re-encode audio in `video.mp4`. The audio is HE-AACv2, but you don't have a HE-AACv2 encoder. So it has to be changed to the more common AAC-LC to allow concatenation with the video generated from the image.

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac main.mp4
   ```
2. Make a video from `image.png` with silent filler audio. It has to have the same attributes as `main.mp4`.

   ```
   ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -i image.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000 -frames:v 2 -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -video_track_timescale 30k -c:a aac image.mp4
   ```

   `-frames:v 2` is used instead of `-frames:v 1` as required for the audio.
3. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file 'image.mp4'
   file 'main.mp4'
   ```
4. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
   ```